# React TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a previous and next button in my react app. I'm trying to get the current index of the page (I have a list of pages stored in an object)

Here's the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Preview({ match }) {
  const [imageName, setImageName] = useState(); //IMPORTANT
  const [images, setImages] = useState(); //IMPORTANT

  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(); //IMPORTANT

  function getIndexByImageName(name) { //IMPORTANT
    Object.keys(images).map((image, index) => {
      if (image === name) return index;
    });
  }

  function importAll(r) {
    let images_ = {};

    r.keys().map((item, index) => {
      images_[item.replace("./", "")] = r(item);
    });

    return images_;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    //This sets the state.
    setImageName(String(match.params.id));
    setImages(importAll(require.context("../coco-images", false, /\.jpg/)));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentIndex(getIndexByImageName(imageName)); //IMPORTANT (This sets the current index. But returns an error)
  }, []);

  return null;
}

export default Preview;
```

The error I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

**Just to be clear, imageName and images is not null or undefined (Because when I console.log it, it has the data that I need).**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

what about assigning a default value to images:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState({}); //IMPORTANT
```

Comment: I cannot because I'm importing it from a folder.

Comment: why can't you assign ```{}``` inside ```useState``` like above? it's just a default value, and when you import your images it would be override

Comment: Hmm. Ok I'll try

Comment: Still no luck. I'll try to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it.

I fixed it by creating a state "`finishedLoading`", and set the state if `finishedLoading` is true

So here is the full code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import loading from "../images/loading.gif";

function Preview({ match }) {
  const [imageName, setImageName] = useState();
  const [images, setImages] = useState();
  const [finishedLoading, setFinishedLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState();

  function setCurrent() {
    if (finishedLoading) {
      Object.keys(images).map((image, index) => {
        if (image === imageName) setCurrentIndex(index);
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  function importAll(r) {
    let images_ = {};

    r.keys().map((item, index) => {
      images_[item.replace("./", "")] = r(item);
    });

    setFinishedLoading(true);
    return images_;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setImageName(String(match.params.id));
    setImages(importAll(require.context("../coco-images", false, /\.jpg/)));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (finishedLoading) setCurrent(); //I've change getIndexByName to setCurrent
  }, [finishedLoading]);

  return null;
}

export default Preview;
```